# Thread run() method execution different on Run and Debug in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, program-entry-point

For the below program different outputs are coming when running and debugging on eclipse.

```
 public class MyClass implements Runnable {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass());
            t.start();
            System.out.print("Started");
            t.join();
            System.out.print("Complete");
        }
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
        }
}
```

When running this as java application the **OUTPUT** is

`Started0123Complete`

When checking in ***Debug*** Mode **OUTPUT** is

`0123StartedComplete`

Can someone help on this? is it because of two threads? `main thread` and the thread which starts with `t.start()`.If yes then why main thread execution is taking more priority to complete first?

Thanks

Comment: There is no guarantee how this will run in  debug/regular mode. If you run it a bunch of times in each mode you'll notice different outputs.

Comment: I literally tried it 5,6 times same output.

Comment: 5 or 6 times is nothing, run that in a loop that executes 1,000 + times you eventually will see a different output

Comment: chancea:I am on 1000+ loop now but don't see a difference

Comment: There are so many variables with hardware, your java configuration,  your OS configuration that it may be where you only see the difference like 1 out of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` times.  For other configurations it might be 1 out of every 100 times.  The answers should clarify why this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's coincidence. You can't control the thread scheduler.

However, in a debug environment, the [debugger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) plugs into your code to inspect values and execution. This inspection increases the amount of work done per thread time slice.

For example, in a regular run, the main thread may only need 1 time slice to create the new thread object, start it, and print the `Started` message. Then a context switch would occur and the second thread would get a chance to work. In a debug run, the main thread would only have enough time to create the new thread object and start the corresponding thread. Then the context switch would occur and the other thread would do its thing.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to this, as this makes more sense.

Answer (score 6):

The order in which the string "Started" and the integers are printed out is undefined by definition. After you call `start`, there is no guarantee that the code in the `run` method will be executed before or after any other statement that appears before the call to `join`. This is the nature of multithreaded applications.

The fact that you see a certain output in debug mode vs run mode is probably purely accidental and might change if you run your code many times or on different platforms/versions of the JVM. If you need deterministic order in this case, the only way you can achieve it is to print a string *before* calling `start` or introduce some other sort of semaphore to force the thread to wait for the main thread or viceversa.

Comment: Actually that's not the /only/ way you can achieve it, some kind of shared mutex between the child and parent threads would also let you do this, e.g. a Semaphore

Comment: @MrWiggles touche, modified my answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to being in debug mode or not.
There is no guarantee of when this gets executed

```
System.out.print("Started"); //this is in the main thread
```

compared to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // this is in the started thread
            System.out.print(i);
        }
```

It can even be

```
01Started23Complete
```

Comment: I like that you showed the possibility of the loop halting half way through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its because of 2 threads But the output is unpredictable.
No, the main thread doesn't get high priority because its MAIN. 
you can't say any particular interleaved execution in multithreads.

In Debug, my guess is you put a break point for main thread so it waits and in the mean time the other thread might have executed.

Comment: This might be the case :) is there any article which helps more understanding on this? if this is really happening the way you said.

Answer (score 0):

In both (Run / Debug) the mode output will be

**Started0123Complete**

You are seeing result **0123StartedComplete**, because you must be having debug point inside main thread code, that’s why.

If you want to understand better, then move the run() method to inside MyClass and put debugger point inside run method now you will see it is printing as **Started0123Complete**.

Internally, Main Thread is creating subthread “t” and when t.start() is being called it is waiting to capture the monitor for thread execution (i.e. run()) and when you are adding debug statement in main thread, sub-thread is entering into monitor and run method is executing and once it completed, main thread is starting again.

Comment: This guy is actually right...The run method is already in class.I just change the debug point to run,but i want to understand whats going on internally

Comment: Internally, Main Thread is creating subthread “t” and when t.start() is being called it is waiting to capture the monitor for thread execution (i.e. run()) and when you are adding debug statement in main thread, sub-thread is entering into monitor and run method is executing and once it completed, main thread is starting again.